# reactjs try catch in render does not catch children errors

Tags: error-handling, reactjs

I'm trying to add error catching to the render function of a component. This works fine when I throw an error in the actual render function, but if there are errors in the children of the component, the try does not catch the errors (or they are intercepted by the child component error handlers, I'm not sure?)

Is there anyway to force the errors to the parent.

```
const SimpleComponent = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        try{
            throw 'new error'
            return <div>{this.props.children}</div>
        }catch(e){
            console.log('error', e);        
        }
    }
})
```

The above works

```
const SimpleComponent = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        try{
            return <div>{this.props.children}</div>
        }catch(e){
            console.log('error', e);        
        }
    }
})

const ChildComponent = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        throw 'child error'
    }
})

<SimpleComponent>
    <ChildComponent />
</SimpleComponent>
```

This above does not catch

Comment: I don't think that's how this `render()` works. You should really be avoiding throwing in any `render()` method. Any work that could possibly throw should probably live somewhere else.

Comment: You should be using Prop Validation (PropTypes) to ensure components are rendering correctly, your example is not the correct use case for a try catch - try and stick to React's built in implementation

Comment: "You should really be avoiding throwing in any render()" => there could already be components from elsewhere that might throw

Comment: you described my exact problem

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use **componentDidCatch**() method from react 16.

Check [this](https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/07/26/error-handling-in-react-16.html) for more info

Answer (score 5):

You can leverage React's BatchingStrategy API to easily wrap a `try/catch` around all of your React code. The benefit of this over `window.onerror` is that you get a nice stack trace in all browsers. Even modern browsers like Microsoft Edge and Safari don't provide stack traces to `window.onerror`.

Note that this solution won't always prevent React from getting into a bad state. However, this solution will at least allow you to handle the error, for example displaying an error banner/modal, or sending stack trace error logs to your service.

Here's what it looks like with React 15.4:

```
import ReactUpdates from "react-dom/lib/ReactUpdates";
import ReactDefaultBatchingStrategy from "react-dom/lib/ReactDefaultBatchingStrategy";

let isHandlingError = false;
const ReactTryCatchBatchingStrategy = {
  // this is part of the BatchingStrategy API. simply pass along
  // what the default batching strategy would do.
  get isBatchingUpdates () { return ReactDefaultBatchingStrategy.isBatchingUpdates; },

  batchedUpdates (...args) {
    try {
      ReactDefaultBatchingStrategy.batchedUpdates(...args);
    } catch (e) {
      if (isHandlingError) {
        // our error handling code threw an error. just throw now
        throw e;
      }

      isHandlingError = true;
      try {
        // replace this with whatever error handling logic you like.
        // e.g. dispatch redux action notifying the app that an error occurred:
        // `store.dispatch({type: "EXCEPTION", payload: e});`
        console.error(e);
      } finally {
        isHandlingError = false;
      }
    }
  },
};

ReactUpdates.injection.injectBatchingStrategy(ReactTryCatchBatchingStrategy);
```

Full writeup here: https://engineering.classdojo.com/blog/2016/12/10/catching-react-errors/

Comment: Hey Byron. This is nice - but where do you actually use it? Where in the app does this go?

Comment: @jamesemanon you can paste this code snippet anywhere in your codebase. the key line in the snippet is `ReactUpdates.injection.injectBatchingStrategy(ReactTryCatchBatchingStrategy);`

In our codebase, we put that inject line in our app initialization file, right before we call `ReactDOM.render()`

Comment: +1. I get the idea and it works for me, thanks! But the function `appTriggeredError` isn't mentioned here or in the linked article. I think you might as well take it out and replace it with e.g. `console.error(e)` or similar (but keep your phrase "replace this with whatever error handling logic you like").

Comment: @TylerCollier good call! yea leaving that in there is just a source of confusion

Comment: @ByronWong When I added it into my App.js, I got error 'ReactUpdates: must provide a batching strategy'

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend the (currently) unstable lifecycle event `unstable_handleError` in your **parent** component.

```
public unstable_handleError(err: any) {

  this.setState({
    error: err
  });

}
```

The error hook will likely become official API in future releases.
See this issue for details

https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/2461

Comment: Could you confirm if this catches errors in children? It did not work for me.

Comment: it catch only if the initial render throws an error. If an update lead to a buggy render it won't work